# Finding the most recent observation earlier than a certain timestamp with XTS

Tags: r, vectorization, xts

I have an `xts` object that looks like this:

```
> q.xts
                                  val
2011-08-31 09:30:00.002357 -1.0135222
2011-08-31 09:30:00.003443 -0.2182679
2011-08-31 09:30:00.005075 -0.5317191
2011-08-31 09:30:00.009515 -1.0639535
2011-08-31 09:30:00.011569 -1.2470759
2011-08-31 09:30:00.012144  0.7678103
2011-08-31 09:30:00.023813 -0.6303432
2011-08-31 09:30:00.024107 -0.5105943
```

I calculate a fixed offset from timestamps in another data frame, `r`. The number of rows in `r` is significantly fewer than the number of rows in `q.xts`.

```
> r
                        time               predict.time
1 2011-08-31 09:30:00.003443 2011-08-31 09:30:00.002443
2 2011-08-31 09:30:00.009515 2011-08-31 09:30:00.008515
3 2011-08-31 09:30:00.024107 2011-08-31 09:30:00.023108
```

The `time` column corresponds to an observation from `q.xts` while the `predict.time` column is 1 millisecond earlier than `time` (less any precision round offs).

What I would like to do is find the last observation from `q.xts` that is equal to or earlier in time for each value of `predict.time`. For the three observations in `r` above I would expect the following matches:

```
                        time               predict.time     (time from q.xts)
1 2011-08-31 09:30:00.003443 2011-08-31 09:30:00.002443  --> 09:30:00.002357
2 2011-08-31 09:30:00.009515 2011-08-31 09:30:00.008515  --> 09:30:00.005075
3 2011-08-31 09:30:00.024107 2011-08-31 09:30:00.023108  --> 09:30:00.012144
```

I had approached this by looping over each row in `r` and performing an `xts subset`. So, for row 1 of `r` I would do:

```
> last(index(q.xts[paste('/', r[1,]$predict.time, sep='')]))
[1] "2011-08-31 09:30:00.002357 CDT"
```

QUESTION: Doing this with a loop seems clunky and awkward. Is there a better way? I would like to end up with another column in `r` that provides the exact time or row number for the corresponding value in `q.xts`.

---

**NOTE:** Use this to build the data I've used for this example:

```
q <- read.csv(tc <- textConnection("
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.002358, -1.01352216
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.003443, -0.21826793
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.005076, -0.53171913
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.009515, -1.06395353
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.011570, -1.24707591
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.012144,  0.76781028
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.023814, -0.63034317
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.024108, -0.51059425"),
     header=FALSE); close(tc)
colnames(q) <- c('datetime', 'val')
q.xts <- xts(q[-1], as.POSIXct(q$datetime))

r <- read.csv(tc <- textConnection("
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.003443
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.009515
       2011-08-31 09:30:00.024108"),
     header=FALSE); close(tc)
colnames(r) <- c('time')
r$time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(r$time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS'))
r$predict.time <- r$time - 0.001
```

Comment: Once you have it, how are you going to use the "column in `r` that provides the exact time or row number for the corresponding value in `q.xts`"?

Comment: I have another tool chain that constructs a feature vector from the rows. There are significantly more columns in the real `q.xts` than just 1. So for each row in `q.xts` that is matched from the timestamps in `r` I will construct a set of features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but this is the best I can come up with at the moment.

```
# create an empty xts object based on r$predict.time
r.xts <- xts(,r$predict.time)
# merge q.xts and r.xts. This will insert NAs at the times in r.xts.
tmp <- merge(q.xts,r.xts)
# Here's the magic:
# lag tmp *backwards* one period, so the NAs appear at the times
# right before the times in r.xts. Then grab the index for the NA periods
tmp.index <- index(tmp[is.na(lag(tmp,-1,na.pad=FALSE))])
# get the rows in q.xts for the times in tmp.index
out <- q.xts[tmp.index]
#                                   val
# 2011-08-31 09:30:00.002357 -1.0135222
# 2011-08-31 09:30:00.005075 -0.5317191
# 2011-08-31 09:30:00.012144  0.7678103
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `findInterval`:

```
findInterval(r$predict.time, index(q.xts))

> q.xts[findInterval(r$predict.time, index(q.xts)),]
                           val
2011-08-31 09:30:00 -1.0135222
2011-08-31 09:30:00 -0.5317191
2011-08-31 09:30:00  0.7678103
```

Your times are `POSIXct` so this should be fairly robust.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. (I imagine this uses less memory/CPU than Joshua's answer on a large xts object, as no merged xts object needs to be made? But I've not benchmarked it.)